# Why has Dotnet build command stopped working?

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, maui

I am debugging a Maui app on Macbook.

Because of the various issues with VS for mac I have been using a build command:

```
dotnet build -t:Run -f net7.0-ios -p:_DeviceName=:v2:udid=0D52415F-8501-4DCF-81F1-84894971D9EB
```

Until last week it worked fine but randomly stopped working. I now get this error:

> /usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/16.4.7099/targets/Xamarin.Shared.Sdk.targets(1830,3):
> error : The app must be built before the arguments to launch the app
> using mlaunch can be computed.
> [/Users/will/PathTo.csproj::TargetFramework=net7.0-ios]

Anyone else seeing this?

Comment: Omit -t:Run to actually build the project.  Or favor dotnet run instead.

Comment: Thanks - removing -t:Run allows the build to work, but now having problems getting it to run. Calling dotnet run I get an error 'The launch profile "(Default)" could not be applied'. How do I set the launch profile to run on the emulator?